# Trying to delete a file with Powershell script ran by a service but issues with uac

Tags: powershell, uac, nagios, access-denied

I'm having issues with a script that will delete a file on the C-Drive of a server. the script looks like this:

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$hostname
)

$StrFileName = "C:\Program Files\NSClient++\nsclient.log"
$LogLocal="c:\Nagios\naf_delete_nscp_log_file.log"

$Date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
"$date : NSClient logfile deletion requested on $hostname" | Out-File -filepath     $LogLocal -Append

If (Test-Path "$strFileName"){
    Remove-Item $strFileName -Force
$Date = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
"$date : NSClient logfile deleted on $hostname" | Out-File -filepath $LogLocal -Append
}
```

The script is initiated from a Nagios quick action which will use nrpe to pass the host as parameter and make the nscp service, which runs as local system, run it. It works perfectly on servers that have no uac enabled, but I can't get it to work on servers with uac. 
I've tried numerous options, but none seem to work. Any tips or advice to get this working on servers with uac enabled is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Willem

Comment: What does your entry look like in the nsclient.ini? You should be able to add `-Verb runAs` to the powershell wrapper `ps1 = cmd /c echo scripts\\%SCRIPT% %ARGS%; exit($lastexitcode) | powershell.exe -command -Verb RunAs -` or in your `[/settings/external scripts/wrapped scripts]` definition.

Comment: `Remove-Item` has a credential parameter, maybe you can solve it that way

Comment: it looks like this atm: naf_delete_nscp_log_file=cmd /c echo scripts\naf_delete_nscp_log_file.ps1 $ARG1$; exit $LastExitCode | powershell.exe -command -
I'll try with the -Verb RunAs

Comment: @Matt It seems -verb RunAs indeed did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your nsclient.ini file I think you just need to adjust either the wrapper for PowerShell or the definition for your script itself with `-Verb RunAs`. In the wrapper, for example, by default you have this:

```
ps1 = cmd /c echo scripts\\%SCRIPT% %ARGS%; exit($lastexitcode) | powershell.exe -command -
```

Which you could update with this

```
ps1 = cmd /c echo scripts\\%SCRIPT% %ARGS%; exit($lastexitcode) | powershell.exe -command -Verb RunAs -
```

**Update from comments**

Would this definition work instead of using the wrapper

```
naf_delete_nscp_log_file=powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -file scripts\naf_delete_nscp_log_file.ps1 "$ARG1$"
```

Comment: Sry man, but it seems I was wrong. It doesn't work yet.
    naf_delete_nscp_log_file=cmd /c echo scripts\naf_delete_nscp_log_file.ps1 $ARG1$; exit $LastExitCode | powershell.exe -command  -Verb RunAs -
Gives:
    Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
At line:1 char:2
+ - <<<< Verb RunAs -
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (-:String) [], ParentContainsErrorR 
   ecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingExpressionAfterOperator

Comment: @user2961029 under what heading do you have that entry in your file. It looks like you have merged a wrapper and a command definition. Also see my updated answer.

Comment: Under [/settings/external scripts/scripts]

Comment: After changing the command in  [/settings/external scripts/scripts] to the new command you proposed (naf_delete_nscp_log_file=powershell.exe -file scripts\naf_delete_nscp_log_file.ps1 "$ARG1$" -Verb RunAs)
The script runs 'forever' in Nagios... and the logfile doesn't get deleted. EDIT: After timeout I get this: CHECK_NRPE: Received 0 bytes from daemon.  Check the remote server logs for error messages.

Comment: @user2961029 What happens when you run that on the command line? Replace $ARG1$ with something else for purpose of testing.

Comment: C:\Program Files\NSClient++\scripts\naf_delete_nscp_log_file.ps1 : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'RunAs'.

Comment: @user2961029 try again at a powershell prompt: `naf_delete_nscp_log_file=powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -file scripts\naf_delete_nscp_log_file.ps1 "$ARG1$"`

Comment: Tried naf_delete_nscp_log_file=powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -file scripts\naf_delete_nscp_log_file.ps1 "$ARG1$" but gave The term 'naf_delete_nscp_log_file=powershell.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
 operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try a
gain.
Tried  powershell.exe -verb RunAs -file .\scripts\naf_delete_nscp_log_file.ps1 $ARG1$ but gave Missing expression after unary operator '-'.
At line:1 char:2